# Angularjs: updated data is not refreshed instantly on the page with $scope.array.push()

Tags: angularjs

The code below is working on my local machine but when this code is pushed to the remote servers it's not working as expected.

Here, I am opening a template to edit:

```
<tr class="read" ng-repeat="records in allExportTemplates | orderBy:'-lastRequestDateTime'">
  <td class="mail-ontact">
    {{records.exportTemplateName}}
  </td>
  <td class="mail-subject">
    {{records.exportFormat}}
  </td>
  <td class="">
    <a class="fa fa-cog" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="editTemplate(records)"></a>
  </td>
```

Controller code for editTemplate:

```
$scope.templateData = {};

$scope.editTemplate = function(templateRecords){
      $('#someModal').modal('show');
      $scope.templateData._id = templateRecords._id;
      $scope.templateData.companyId = templateRecords.companyId;
      $scope.templateData.templateName = templateRecords.exportTemplateName;
      $scope.templateData.exportFormat = templateRecords.exportFormat;
    }
```

and below is the code to update the template:

```
<form role="form" name = "edittemplateForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="exampleInputEmail1" contenteditable="true">Template Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Monthly" name="templateName" ng-model="templateData.templateName" ng-required="true">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" name="selectExportFormat">Select Export Format</label>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="templateData.exportFormat">
      <option>XML</option>
      <option>JSON</option>
    </select>
```

outside the form

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updateTemplate(edittemplateForm)" ng-disabled="edittemplateForm.$invalid">Update</button>
```

And this is the controller code to update:

```
$scope.updateTemplate = function(editTemplateForm){

    someSrv.updateTemplate($scope.templateData)
    .success( function(response) {
        if($scope.allExportTemplates.length){
            for(i =0;i < $scope.allExportTemplates.length ;i++){
                if($scope.allExportTemplates[i]._id == response.data._id){
                    $scope.allExportTemplates.splice(i,1);
                    break;
                }                
            }
            $('#someModal').modal('hide');
            $scope.allExportTemplates.push(response.data);
        }   
    })
```

On updating a template, I am removing the old data from the array. But, it doesn't show up on the page instantly and correct data is shown only after the page is refreshed. Response contains old data whereas, it works perfectly on my local machine, response has the latest data and shows up on the page directly after hiding the modal. But, doesn't seem to work on the remote servers.

Any clue of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, posting it here so that it might help someone in the future.

**It was a mongoose related issue. Upgrading the mongoose version on the server, did the trick.**